# how to replace the existing tags text in the xml from a text box in web page

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a php file which has a text box which will append text to xml file and that will reflect back in the webpage,
I would like to change all the text inside that tags in xml,
please help me for writing the script to do that,
[xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQaWO.jpg)

[Php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBmna.jpg)

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: **I need a script to do that?,**. Well, i don't have script.

Comment: Added code through the images, Please look into that and help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If we put this script in the message box it will change all those
>   messages to Whatever you want

```
<script>
 var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
    x[i].innerHTML="Whatever you want";
    }
</script>
```